# PHP: How to loop through properties with sequential names

Tags: php, oop

If I have a table with columns called image1, image2, image3, etc and I pulled those in an object-oriented manner, like this:

```
$images->image1
$images->image2
$images->image3
```

etc.

Is there any way to process these in a loop? Something like:

```
for (i=1; i<count($images); $i++) {
    $array[$i] = $images->image?
}
```

I realize the above won't work, but was wondering if someone could tell me a way that will work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulling them from the DB in an array might be a better option, but you can do it with objects by using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
for ($i = 1; i < $length; $i++) {
    $array[] = $images->{'image' . $i};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead.

However, you can also use [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543792/php-variable-variables) for this madder.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; i < $len; $i++) {
    $array[] = $images->{'image' + $i};
}
```